# How can i pass a Map in angular 2+ from html template to custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives, angular6, es6-map

I'm trying to pass a map from an angular html template to a custom directive.

I guess I succeed to pass it as an object, because I can console.log the map values. But when I try to set or get values from the map I get an error.

My code:

html template

```
<canvas id="seatsCanvasMain" 
        name="seatsCanvasMain" 
        appTheaterMap [takenSeatsMap]="show.theaterMap" 
        style="border:1px solid black">
</canvas>
```

Directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTheaterMap]'
})
export class TheaterMapDirective {
  canvas;
  @Input() takenSeatsMap: any;


  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    this.canvas = this.el.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.canvas.onclick = (e) => {
      console.log(this.takenSeatsMap);//this will console log the map as an object. at first it seems that it passed correctly
      this.takenSeatsMap.get('4-4'); // ERROR TypeError: _this.takenSeatsMap.get is not a function

    }

  }

}
```

Here is the console.log [image]

Anybody knows what can I do? 
I would also appreciate other methods on how to pass this map to the directive

Many thanks

Comment: Please, add the error to your post, so we could help you out better

Comment: added a picture of the console.log

Comment: By the looks of it, you're not passing a Map object at all. You're just passing a JSON object.

Comment: is `show.theaterMap` an actual Map? it looks like a regular json object. Maps should print like this in the console: `Map(1) {2 => "b"}`

Comment: it's a map in my Nodejs server. i guess i raised another question. is it possible to send a map via http request from server side (nodejs) to frontend side (angular 6)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native `map` to the `Object` object.

```
Object.keys(this.map)
```

will return an array of keys.

try to access as `this.takenSeatsMap.4-4`

Comment: Why would you initialize an input? Use types... `@Input() takenSeatsMap: Map`

Comment: see whether   @Input() takenSeatsMap: Map works it will give you 'Generic type 'Map<K, V>' requires 2 type argument(s)'

Comment: this.takenSeatsMap.4-4 will result in error as this will be accessing number property on an object, instead if object key is '4-4' (should be string otherwise it will be evaluated as 0), so try accessing it as this.takenSeatsMap['4-4'], this will result in desired result.